# Grouping Anagrams using OrderedDictionary: TypeError issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, typeerror

I was a assigned to group ana grams together in a list of lists, lexcicographicaly.

Below is one of the test cases:

*Input:* 
`eat tea tan ate nat bat`

*Output:*

`ate eat tea
 bat
 nat tan`

However, I keep getting a typeError like this: `TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable`

I managed to fix this error by changing `anagramDict = OrderedDict(list)` to `anagramDict = defaultdict(list)` but this resulted the code to print all three line in a **random order** every time the program is ran.

Is there a way to fix this so that the program outputs **exactly** like the way it is shown above?

This is what i have done so far:

```
import sys
from collections import *
def findAnagrams(string):
    anagramDict = OrderedDict(list)
    for word in string:
        key = ''.join(sorted(word))
        anagramDict[key].append(word)
    return anagramDict

def main():
    for string in sys.stdin:
        stringList = string.split()
        if len(stringList) == 0:
           break
        anagramDict = findAnagrams(stringList)
        for key,anagrams in anagramDict.items():
            if len(anagrams) >=1:
                print(' '.join(sorted(anagrams)))
        print ()
main()
```

Note: the machine that runs this programs reads input from stdin/keyboard and prints the output to console(stdout).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot pass [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) a argument like `list` . Because when using [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) the argument to it should be an iterable (like list of tuples, etc) , from which the ordered dictionary would be created.

When using OrderedDict, you can use [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) instead to get similar effect. Example -

```
def findAnagrams(string):
    anagramDict = OrderedDict()
    for word in string:
        key = ''.join(sorted(word))
        anagramDict.setdefault(key, []).append(word)
    return anagramDict
```

---

Also, another thing to note is that `OrderedDict` keeps the order in which the keys are sent to it, it does not sort in lexicographic order.

For that an easy way would be to sort it when trying to iterate over it in the `main()` function. Example -

```
def main():
    s = [input()]
    for string in s:
        stringList = string.split()
        if len(stringList) == 0:
           break
        anagramDict = findAnagrams(stringList)
        for key, anagrams in sorted(anagramDict.items() ,key=lambda x: sorted(x[1])):
            if len(anagrams) >=1:
                print(' '.join(sorted(anagrams)))
        print ()
```

For this method, you do not even need to use `OrderedDict`, you can simply use a `defaultdict` as you were using, or a normal dict with `dict.setdefault` .

Demo -

Input -

```
eat tea tan ate nat bat
```

Output -

```
ate eat tea
bat
nat tan
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out once again. This avoids the code to get TypeError. However, I am still finding it hard to get the order of the output right. Any suggestions?

Comment: @AnandSKumar He wants lexicographic order per the question.

Comment: @Eninfo `OrderedDict` means "preserves the order you add items" not "sorts the items that are added"

Comment: @zstewart Yes, correct, I updated that in the answer. And also updated a way to get the order he requires.

Comment: Exactly as shown above: `ate eat tea` on the first line `bat` on the second line and `nat tan` on the third line

Comment: @Eninfo Can you be more specific than "the order shown"? Lines should be sorted lexicographically, but should they be sorted by first word in that line? Should each line be sorted as well?

Comment: @zstewart Yes each line should be sorted as well. The words in each line are already sorted lexic'ally